# How to Map A Table Column With Many Different Columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
I have two tables as follow: 
1. products :
columns:
id integer,
Sku string,
....

2. cars :
columns:
id integer,
brand integer,
type_of_car enum,
...
```

I have considered creating a pivot table product_car where a product id is going to be mapped to either an id of a car or type_of_car.

Now the problem I am facing is, I don't know how exactly to map two columns of the joining table (ie. id or type_of_car of Car table) to a single table (ie.Id of the product) in a relational database.

Can Some On Suggest me alternate approach too ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from 
    cars 
    inner join products p1 on p1.id=cars.id
    inner join products p2 on p2.type_of_car=cars.id
```

This is the sample query to give you the idea,don't know your table schema and data